# In Firefox, how to open "file, edit ..." menu while keeping menuAccessKeyFocuses set to false

Tags: firefox

The default behavior of Firefox is for the Alt key to toggle the menu bar, but I like using Alt for dragging Windows in Gnome, so I disabled that behavior by going to `about:config` and setting `menuAccessKeyFocuses` to false. (Of course, I can also disable Alt toggling by permanently turning on the menu, but I would rather save the space)

However, with `menuAccessKeyFocuses = False`, there's one weakness: if on the rare occasion I DO want to use the menu just once, the only way to do so is to right click the blank space to the right of my tabs and enable "Menu bar". However, doing so also resets `menuAccessKeyFocuses` back to true. This means that if I want the following:

- hide menu bar most of the time
- don't toggle using Alt
- use menu bar rarely

I need to constantly set `menuAccessKeyFocuses` back to false just to retain those three properties.

Is there an easier way?

(I'm using Firefox 102.15.1esr in Debian 12)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an easier way. First set `menuAccessKeyFocuses` to false, of course. Then, on the rare chance when you want the menu, just press Alt+F to open the file menu (which makes the rest of the menu appear)

Using this method, `menuAccessKeyFocuses` stays false, and the menu disappears as soon as you click out of it. Alt button by itself continues to not toggle the menu.